# How to create a dict of functions in Python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, lambda, structure

I'm writing a database migration script in Python, in which I create a dictionary which can migrate the database between versions. I currently do this as follows:

```
def from1To2():
    pass  # migration script here
def from2To1():
    pass  # migration script here
# etc

migrations = {
    1: {'up': from1To2},
    2: {'down': from2To1, 'up': from2To3},
    3: {'down': from3To2, 'up': from3To4},
    4: {'down': from4To3},
}
```

But every time I create a new migration, I need to write two migration scripts (up and down) AND put them in the migrations dictionary. Since the migration functions are really small (normally two lines), I thought of directly writing them in the migrations dict. In Javascript this would look something like:

```
migrations = {
    1: {
        'up': function(){ addSomeColumn(); recordChange(); }, 
        'down': function(){ dropSomeColumn(); recordChange(); }
    },
    2: etc
}
```

Because the migration functions are often two lines, I don't think I can use lambda functions. Does anybody know any other way of directly writing functions in a dict in Python? All tips are welcome!

Comment: And if you create a dict of a list of lambda? Like: `migrations = {1: [lambda: add_some_column(), lambda: record_change()]}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a custom decorator:

```
migrations = {}

def migrate(old_version, new_version):
    assert abs(new_version-old_version)==1

    def decorator(f):
        direction = 'up' if new_version > old_version else 'down'
        if old_version not in migrations:
            migrations[old_version] = {}
        migrations[old_version][direction] = f
        return f
    return decorator

@migrate(1, 2)
def upgrade():
    pass  # migration script here

@migrate(2, 1)
def downgrade():
    pass  # migration script here

@migrate(2, 3)
def upgrade():
    pass  # migration script here
# etc

print(migrations)
```

For which the output is something like:

```
{1: {'up': <function upgrade at 0x02BE4588>}, 2: {'down': <function downgrade at 0x02BE4618>, 'up': <function upgrade at 0x02BE4540>}}
```

The decoration is responsible for updating the `migrations` dictionary, but this way the functions can have any name or re-use the same names, or can be in other modules (e.g. have one file for version 1 to 2 and rollback and another for 2 to 3 and rollback).

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use a lambda:

```
>>> function_dictionary = {'capitalize': lambda text: text.capitalize()}
>>> function_dictionary['capitalize']('word')
'Word'
```

Comment: But as I describe in my question: as far as I know, you can't run lambda functions with two lines of code. And many of my migration functions contain two lines of code..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lambda: addSomeColumn() and recordChange()` providing that your functions will return `True`.